# z-index on a table row not working

Tags: html, css, position, z-index

I have a table and a vertical div that suppose to be on top of all the rows but one. It has `position:absolute; z-index:1` and the row has `position:relative; z-index:2` and it doesn't work.

http://codepen.io/ilyador/pen/XJKjVw/?editors=110

The grey vertical line (`.marker`) should be under the `40Db` row (`.current-volume`), and visible over all the others like it is now.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if `tr` elements can take z-index in that way or not, but it seems to work fine if you apply your z-index to the nested `td` elements instead. You will need to apply a background to them rather than the rows, however, so that you don't see through them.